# Exporting MySQL table to csv one row divided in to multiple rows

Tags: c#, asp.net, export-to-csv

I am trying to export database table to csv file. However file gets converted & downloading but one single row data is been divided in to many rows which creates problem. Following code I found from aspsnippets which I am using. Is there any problem with kind of records I have which contains HTML tags in.

```
string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("conio").ConnectionString;
using (MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(constr)) {
    using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * FROM products")) {
        using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter()) {
            cmd.Connection = con;
            sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
            using (DataTable dt = new DataTable()) {
                sda.Fill(dt);

                //Build the CSV file data as a Comma separated string.
                string csv = string.Empty;

                foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
                    //Add the Header row for CSV file.
                    csv += column.ColumnName + ',';
                }

                //Add new line.
                csv += Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf;

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows) {
                    foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns) {
                        //Add the Data rows.
                        csv += row(column.ColumnName).ToString().Replace(",", ";") + ',';
                    }

                    //Add new line.
                    csv += Constants.vbCr + Constants.vbLf;
                }

                //Download the CSV file.
                Response.Clear();
                Response.Buffer = true;
                Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=Products.csv");
                Response.Charset = "";
                Response.ContentType = "application/text";
                Response.Output.Write(csv);
                Response.Flush();
                Response.End();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Snapshot

Highlighted is begining of each row. In between rows created which should be in same row which highlighted.
[image]

Comment: As you have mentioned; it is because of the HTML tags. You will have to use the Text Qualifier. say "

Comment: @Anand can you post solution. Thanks

Comment: Try adding a double quote around each cell value. Let me know if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
csv += "\"" + row(column.ColumnName).ToString().Replace(",", ";") + "\"" + ',';
```

Change this line in your code and let me know if it helps.

If there are special characters, they should be put inside a double quote.

So, your row should look like below

```
id,name,htmltags
"1","abcd","<td>values</td>"
```

Your code should be like

```
For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows 
For Each column As DataColumn In dt.Columns 
'Add the Data rows. 
Dim str As String 
str = row(column.ColumnName).ToString() 
str = Replace(str, """", """""") 
csv += """" & str & """" & "," 
Next 

'Add new line. 
csv += vbCr & vbLf 
Next
```

Comment: Hi Anand. Your solution almost worked for me. Still little problem is there where it finds tag paragraph <p> it again breaks the line. What could I do for that?

Comment: @SUN could you please paste the single row (may be masked) for testing? Because for me it is working even with <p> tag

Comment: Is there a quote around it?

Comment: Basically, what we are saying here is "what is there inside double quote, treat it as a cell value". If you have double quote inside a cell value, you will have to escape them as well. So the issue is not with tag <p>; it is because of the double quote around it.

Comment: Yes. Double quotes(") occured there where row gets break.

Comment: Can you show how to escape from (") as well please.

Comment: You will have to handle that inside your code. May be something like replacing a double quote, by two double quotes. string str = row(column.ColumnName).ToString().Replace(",", ";") ; str = str.Replace("\"",""""); csv += str + ",";

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125064/discussion-between-sun-and-anand).

Answer (score 0):

You need to replace `'\n', '\t'` and extra spaces to `""` the same way you did with , and ; using replace() or RegEx and then add it to file.

in C#, it is safe to use Environment.NewLine for output. But when you're extracting from database, you need to check for `\n` or `\t` as most databases use them as delimiters.

Something like this also works. (its lengthy but works)

```
csv += row(column.ColumnName).ToString().Replace(",", ";").Replace('\n',"").Replace('\t',"") + ',';
```